# Python RuntimeError: More keyword list entries (5) than format specifiers (1)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am trying to develop a Simple Sound2Light Application for my Raspberry Pi in Python.
I'm using the Impulse Library written by Ian Halpern (https://github.com/ianhalpern/Impulse)

However I first tried to extract 3 Values (Sub,Mid,Hi) from the Audio Array Impulse is delivering me.

This is the Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, os, time

import impulse

def draw ( ):
    fft = True

    audio_sample_array = impulse.getSnapshot( fft )

    if fft:
        ffted_array = list( audio_sample_array )

        # start drawing spectrum

        red = 0
        green = 0
        blue = 0

        for i in range(0,20):
            blue += ffted_array[i]      

        for i in range(21,41):
            green += ffted_array[i]     

        for i in range(42,62):
            red += ffted_array[i]       

        print red,
        print blue,
        print green

    return False


def main(args):
    try:
        while True:
            draw()
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        import ctypes
        libc = ctypes.CDLL('libc.so.6')
        libc.prctl(15, os.path.split( sys.argv[ 0 ] )[ 1 ], 0, 0, 0)
    except:
        pass

    sys.exit( main( sys.argv ) )
    main( sys.argv )
```

However this Code ist Running flawlessly on my Laptop (archlinux x64 python 2.7)

```
[felix@felix-think impulse]$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.3
```

but fails to run on my Rapsberry Pi (Running Raspbian)

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/music2light $ python --version
Python 2.7.3
```

This is the ErrorMessage

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/music2light $ python main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 56, in <module>
    sys.exit( main( sys.argv ) )
  File "main.py", line 40, in main
    draw()
  File "main.py", line 21, in draw
    for i in range(0,20):
RuntimeError: More keyword list entries (5) than format specifiers (1)
```

I'm tried to Google for it but found nothing... The only thing I found out is, that the Error is thrown by the getargs.c File (http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/release27-maint/Python/getargs.c)

```
if (IS_END_OF_FORMAT(*format)) {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_RuntimeError,
                     "More keyword list entries (%d) than "
                     "format specifiers (%d)", len, i);
        return cleanreturn(0, freelist);
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)
Felix

Comment: This might be a bug in the Impulse library - `static char *kwlist[] = { "fft" };` in `impulsemodule.c` should have a `NULL` entry in the array to signify the end (a Python requirement). But it doesn't explain why it would work on some platforms...